# NuGet Curl C++. Unresolved external symbol only with x64 build

Tags: c++, curl, visual-studio-2017

I have already searched a solution on *Google* and here on *SO* I have only found some questions about the non-NuGet lib package.

([This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383630(v=vs.85).aspx) is the NuGet package. I use the **7.52.1** version because the *7.53.0* has some compatibility problems with the program I'm developing even with the x86 build)

My problem is that when I want to build my project to **x64**, the linker gives me **149** errors about an *unresolved external symbol* in **libcurl.lib** (**openssl.obj**), (**md5.obj**) and (**curl_ntlm_core.obj**).
I'm 90% sure that everything is ok about the project settings for the x64 part, I have *verified and re-verified* a **lot** of times before asking here for help.

This is the code I use (**who works on the x86 build**):

```
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "wldap32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#define CURL_STATICLIB 
#include <curl\curl.h>

class _Curl {

private:

    static size_t _CURLWriteCallback(void* contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp) {
        ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);

        return size * nmemb;
    }

public:

    static BOOL DownloadString(const std::string &URL, std::string &strGET, LONG CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS = 1000) {
        CURL*    _CURL;
        CURLcode _CURL_RESPONSE;

        _CURL = curl_easy_init();
        if (_CURL) {
            curl_easy_setopt(_CURL, CURLOPT_URL, URL.c_str());
            curl_easy_setopt(_CURL, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS);
            curl_easy_setopt(_CURL, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, _CURLWriteCallback);
            curl_easy_setopt(_CURL, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &strGET);
            _CURL_RESPONSE = curl_easy_perform(_CURL);
            curl_easy_cleanup(_CURL);
        }
        if (_CURL_RESPONSE == CURLE_OK) { return TRUE; }
        return FALSE;
    }
};
```

I have also tried to change this part

```
#pragma comment(lib, "wldap32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "crypt32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
```

With

```
#pragma comment(lib, "wldap64.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "crypt64.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_64.lib")
```

But seems that the names of the libs are hardcoded to *32.lib

I want to say sorry if this will be a duplicate, but I *can't* find a solution for *my case*.

P.S: I'm using *Visual Studio Community 2017*

**Thank you for your time**!

**[UPDATE]**

I *can't* seem to find a solution to make curl to work also with the x64 build.

So I have solved using [WinINet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383630(v=vs.85).aspx) (because I only need to download the *HTML* *content* of a Web page as a **string**).

I have created a small class to do this, the "only" problem is that WinINet seems to be much slower (*approximately with a 48% slower [I have only tested with some files large between 100KB and 800KB]*).

This is the class I have written if someone has the *same problem* and want to use a "*workaround*"

```
#ifndef _NET_H
#define _NET_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinINet.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "WinINet.lib")

class _Net {

public:

    static BOOL DownloadString(const std::basic_string<TCHAR> &URL, std::basic_string<TCHAR> &RETURN, DWORD CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS = 1000, DWORD CONNECTION_RETRIES = 1) {
        if (InternetCheckConnection(_T("http://www.google.com"), FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION, 0) == FALSE)
            return 0;

        HINTERNET _hOpen = InternetOpen(0, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, 0, 0, 0);
        if (!_hOpen)
            return 0;

        InternetSetOption(_hOpen, INTERNET_OPTION_SEND_TIMEOUT 
                                & INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT 
                                & INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, &CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS, sizeof(DWORD));
        InternetSetOption(_hOpen, INTERNET_OPTION_CONNECT_RETRIES, &CONNECTION_RETRIES,    sizeof(DWORD));

        DWORD _f = INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE             | 
                   INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE                 | 
                   INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE         | 
                   INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE         | 
                   INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID | 
                   INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID;

        HINTERNET _hInternet = InternetOpenUrl(_hOpen, URL.c_str(), 0, 0, _f, 0);
        if (!_hInternet) {
            CloseHandle(_hOpen);
            return 0;
        }

        TCHAR _data[2]; ZeroMemory(&_data, sizeof(_data));
        DWORD _dataReceivedSize;
        std::basic_string<TCHAR> _strResult;

        while (InternetReadFile(_hInternet, _data, 1, &_dataReceivedSize) && _dataReceivedSize)
            _strResult += _data;

        CloseHandle(_hInternet);
        CloseHandle(_hOpen);

        if (_strResult.length() == 0) 
            return 0;

        RETURN = _strResult;
        return 1;
    }
};
#endif //_NET_H
```

This will download the Web page from the given url, and return the content in the `RETURN` string.

```
std::string content;
_Net::DownloadString("https://www.google.com", content);
```

Comment: it's worth noting that there is no `crypt64.lib` etc the names are the same as the 32bit versions.

Comment: Looks like CURL depends on a few things you're not including from nuget.

Comment: @Mgetz I have tried to change the names only to be 100% sure.
Anyway, I really don't understand where is the problem, and I have solved with the WinINet workaround because I can't permit to spend too much time trying to find a solution for the Curl errors.
Striezel I have deleted the "answer", I'm sorry!

Comment: The issue is you probably don't have 64bit versions of those libraries built as .lib files nor do you have the project set to find them if you did.

Comment: @Mgetz Most probably you're right, OpenSSL, LibZip e etc.. was automatically downloaded and installed when I have installed Curl 32/64bit from NuGet, so I was thinking that also the dependent libs was downloaded for both 32/64.
Anyway, thank you for your time.